# Use of Dispatcher in cglib

Tags: java, proxy, cglib

Can someone please explain the use of **Dispatcher** in **cglib** proxies ?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you look at [Dispatcher](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/proxy/Dispatcher.html) and [Usage of Dispatcher](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.springsource.com@net.sourceforge.cglib%24com.springsource.net.sf.cglib@2.2.0@net%24sf%24cglib%24proxy@Dispatcher&type=type&k=u)